# Analysis of coefficients of $x^k+\frac1{x^k}$ polynomials

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, symmetry, pattern-recognition

Given $x+\dfrac1x=n$, I derived several expressions in terms of $n$ to solve for $x^k+\dfrac1{x^k}$ and put them in a chart as shown below. My questions is  how are the coefficients of these polynomials related? I have observed that the first coefficient is $1$, the second coefficient is $-k$, and the signs always alternate.

[image: Chart of polynomials]

Comment: In case the chart is unclear, if $x+\dfrac1x=3$ (third column where $n=3$) then $x^3+\dfrac1{x^3}=18$ which I put into the second row where $k=3$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $x + 1/x = n$, writing $x = \exp(it)$ we have $\cos(t) = n/2$.
Then $x^k + 1/x^k = \exp(ikt) + \exp(-ikt) = 2 \cos(kt) = 2 T_k(n/2)$
where $T_k$ is the $k$'th [Chebyshev polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind.  Thus for $k=11$, 
$$T_{11}(x) = 1024\,{x}^{11}-2816\,{x}^{9}+2816\,{x}^{7}-1232\,{x}^{5}+220\,{x}^{3}-
11\,x$$ so you get
$$ 2 T_{11}(n/2) = {n}^{11}-11\,{n}^{9}+44\,{n}^{7}-77\,{n}^{5}+55\,{n}^{3}-11\,n$$

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I have determined from the definition $T_{n}(x) = \dfrac{(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})^n+(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})^n}2$ that if $x+\dfrac1x=n$, $x^k+\dfrac1{x^k}=(a+\sqrt{a^2-1})^k+(a-\sqrt{a^2-1})^k$ where $a=\dfrac n2$.

Comment: Simplified and in terms of $n$ this becomes $\dfrac{(n+\sqrt{n^2-4})^k+(n-\sqrt{n^2-4})^k}{2^k}$.